# Why is nothing showing up on the collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview and I have an array with a string username which is connected to parse, but when I run the program the collectionview does not display anything. I hardcoded it by manually putting in values in the array and it worked, but once I retrieve strings from parse it does not work. How do I fix this?

```
var arrayOfFriendsNames = [String]()
var arrayOfFriendsTest: [String] = ["fire.png, fire.png, fire.png"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
            self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
            print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)
        }
    })
 self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfFriendsNames.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView


    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.friendpic.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfFriendsTest[indexPath.row])
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Set datasource and delegates of collectionview.

Comment: I have done that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reload after finished getting data from DB

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
            self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
            print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.collectionView.reloadData() 
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're calling `reloadData` method on your `UICollectionView` instance when you finish loading data from `Parse`. If yes, check your constraints for your `UICollectionView` and make sure that they are correct. One other possibility can be `Parse` returning no data to your code, so make sure that your array has valid data in it.

The issue with your code is the place you're calling `self.collectionView.reloadData()`. You'd need to call it inside your `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

    for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
        self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
        print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)
    }
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

You can also use `GCD` approach as @anhtu answered

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on `collectionView: numberOfItemsInSection:`, does it get called? If yes, what's the value for `arrayOfFriendsNames.count`

Comment: arrayOfFriendsNames is populated, it corresponds to the parse database, but arrayOfFriendsNames does not appear in the console when I put a breakpoint.